# SharePoint 2007 RichHtmlField has inline style that is causing issues in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, moss

I am working on an intranet project that is having the majority of its users move up to ie8 soon. A bug was detected where when attempting to create/edit a page, the rich html editor boxes would be squeezed compared to what they look like in any other browser.

I found the offending style, its inline and its:

```
style="display:inline-block"
```

Now if it was just "inline" then it would be fine. However, it is not.

I have attempted to override the PrefixStyleSheet attribute in the master page and have a custom style in the main css file, but it is not working at all.

I have heard that a control adapter might be helpful to post process the html but i am unsure on how to use one.

Is there any advice you guys can give me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, using JQuery "hacks" in the master page header is the most convenient approach, without messing up the system css or the backend.

Find the element you want to override the style to a custom style, and assign your custom style. Be careful if the override is page layout specific, then might add to the page layout header placeholder instead.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I figured that. There are alot of custom formats for this intranet, so im going to try and find a spot to add a snipped to find and override it in all pages.